# Copy multiple files from multiple folders into a specified folder?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy 20+ files, each housed by unique folders, into a single folder.

I created the below code.

I get

> Compile Error: Object required.

Folder name is the date of the report (eg. 090118), hence, I decided to use a loop until the end of the month (931). I also added error handling code to skip the holidays and weekends.

```
Sub CopyFiles()

    Dim NewFolder As String
    Dim NDay As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim Month As Variant

    Set Month = InputBox("Enter month, eg. 01-January")
    NewFolder = "C:\Results\Trading\2018\" & Month & "\Backtest Daily Files\Daily GS\" 'Don't forget to edit this
    NDay = 901

    On Error Resume Next

    Do While NDay < 931

        FileName = Dir("C:\Reports\2018\" & Month & "\0" & NDay & "18\GS_Futures*.cs*")

        FileCopy FileName, NewFolder

        NDay = NDay + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Does each folder contain only file to be copied

Comment: Each folder contains several files but I only need to copy one specific file. 
There's a common factor when it comes to the file name, if this helps. For example:
C:\Folder_01\Balance_Sheet_01
C:\Folder_02\Balance_Sheet_02
.
.
.
C:\Folder_20\Balance_Sheet_20

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most efficient way, however you could use a loop to select the file and then move it useing `copyfile`.

```
Sub Move_File()
Dim myFSO As Object
Dim startFolder As String, endFolder As String
Dim startFile As String
startFile = "test.xls"

For i = 1 To 20
startFolder = Range(Cells(i,2),Cells(i,2))
endFolder = "C:\Test\"
myFSO.copyfile startFolder & startFile, endFolder & endFile, True
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Just an FYI, `startFolder = Range(Cells(i,2),Cells(i,2))` can be replaced with `startFolder = Cells(i, 2).value`

Comment: Thank you, @Sam! Could you kindly comment on my edited question? I tried using Turtle's answer but it didn't quite fit with my requirements at the moment. I created a code but unfortunately, it won't run.

Comment: Why are you using  'Set Month'? Deleting the 'Set' and just leaving: 'Month = InputBox("Enter month, eg. 01-January")' I don't get any errors anymore.